# How to serve static pages in Vue Vite?

Tags: vue.js, assets, vite

I have an app built using Vuetify 3 and Firebase. But then I need to *also* host a set of conventional, non-Vue HTML as landing/informational pages complete with their own JS and CSS. I'm going about this by using Vue Router to redirect non-authenticated visits to `/welcome`. With Vue CLI I just need to put all the site files in `public/welcome` and run the build.

How do I do this with Vite?

Comment: It's the same in Vite and covered in the docs. "I'm going about this by using Vue Router" - how exactly? Vue router is supposed to use components. If you need to redirect from vue app, use window.location.

Comment: I'm going to use `beforeEnter` on `/` route. If it's routed into without proper auth in cookie/session storage, set `window.location` to `/welcome`.